# Laravel Passport JWT authentication failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-passport

Out of the blue I started getting this error in production when trying to create a JWT through passport, running on Ubuntu/apache2. As far as I'm aware nothing was changed on the server, no installs, no deployments, it just stopped working.

PHP 7.3

OpenSSL 1.0.1f

Laravel 5.8

```
production.ERROR: There was an error while creating the signature: error:04066044:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_encrypt:internal error {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): There was an error while creating the signature: error:04066044:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_encrypt:internal error at /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php:27)
[stacktrace]
#0 /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php(36): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\OpenSSL->createHash('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key))
#1 /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Builder.php(470): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\BaseSigner->sign('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key))
#2 /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Builder.php(450): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Builder->createSignature(Array, Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Rsa\\Sha256), Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key))
#3 /api/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Entities/Traits/AccessTokenTrait.php(41): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Builder->getToken()
#4 /api/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/ResponseTypes/BearerTokenResponse.php(28): Laravel\\Passport\\Bridge\\AccessToken->convertToJWT(Object(League\\OAuth2\\Server\\CryptKey))
#5 /api/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationServer.php(202): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\ResponseTypes\\BearerTokenResponse->generateHttpResponse(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\Response))
#6 /api/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(63): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\AuthorizationServer->respondToAccessTokenRequest(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\Response))
#7 /api/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/HandlesOAuthErrors.php(28): Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController->Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\{closure}()
#8 /api/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(65): Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController->withErrorHandling(Object(Closure))
#9 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(48): Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController->issueToken(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\ServerRequest))
#10 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController), 'issueToken')
#11 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#12 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(680): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#13 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(58): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#21 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
```

I also just noticed another version of this error. Nothing changed so I don't know why this error did.

Note this bit: `rsa routines:RSA_setup_blinding:BN lib`

```
production.ERROR: There was an error while creating the signature: error:04088003:rsa routines:RSA_setup_blinding:BN lib {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): There was an error while creating the signature: error:04088003:rsa routines:RSA_setup_blinding:BN lib at /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php:27)
[stacktrace]
#0 /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php(36): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\OpenSSL->createHash('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key))
#1 /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Builder.php(470): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\BaseSigner->sign('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key))
#2 /api/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Builder.php(450): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Builder->createSignature(Array, Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Rsa\\Sha256), Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key))
#3 /api/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Entities/Traits/AccessTokenTrait.php(41): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Builder->getToken()
#4 /api/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/ResponseTypes/BearerTokenResponse.php(28): Laravel\\Passport\\Bridge\\AccessToken->convertToJWT(Object(League\\OAuth2\\Server\\CryptKey))
#5 /api/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationServer.php(202): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\ResponseTypes\\BearerTokenResponse->generateHttpResponse(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\Response))
#6 /api/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(63): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\AuthorizationServer->respondToAccessTokenRequest(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\Response))
#7 /api/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/HandlesOAuthErrors.php(28): Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController->Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\{closure}()
#8 /api/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(65): Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController->withErrorHandling(Object(Closure))
#9 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(48): Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController->issueToken(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\ServerRequest))
#10 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController), 'issueToken')
#11 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#12 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(680): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#13 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(58): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#21 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
```

Comment: Which version of passport you have installed ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue today. Spent a lot of time and not found solution.
And this algo helped for me

1. sudo certbot
2. choose needed domain then enter '2' two times to renew ssl certificat
3. then delete keys from storage folder, also delete from database table oauth_clients
4. php artisan passport:install
5. check permissions for keys in storage folder
6. sudo service apache2 restart

And after that laravel passport started to login users. It seems for me that some problem was with certificat, because the same bunch of commands without certificat renew not fix auth work.